# Change the Column width and Position programmatically in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, crystal-reports, position, width

I want to create a report that has dynamic fields (columns). in the simpler words, there are 15 optional fields for user and the user will select 6 of them to be displayed in report.

so, for solution, I added all the columns in the report. and now I want to hide all non-selected columns and also change the width and position of the visible columns.

how can I do that in vb.net 2010 by coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the width is concerned, you could use something like this, which will change the height and width (0 of course will hide it, so change it to a value that suits you).

```
Dim RptDoc As New ReportDocument
 Dim _fldName As FieldObject
 _fldName = RptDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("fieldObjectName")
_fldName.Width = 0
_fldName.Height = 0
```

About moving an object, you could try something like this:

```
myReport _myReport = new myReport ();
myReport .Section1.ReportObjects["myline"].Top = 10;
```

You need to be aware of the Section naming in your report and the correct line reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to visualize the data I would suggest you to use a grid. Crystal report is good for static structures. If you need to export the grid to a pdf or Excel then you can use this tool:
http://r-tag.com/Pages/BlogPost/1
Get a free license here: http://r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: Apparently, the site was changed. Links should work now.